# Local CSS background-image not displaying

Tags: html, css, image

I'm trying to display a local `background-image` in CSS. It's in the same folder as index.html and it's not displaying.

```
    .image {
        width:100px;
        background-image: url('PIC1.jpg');
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: it is expecting to be in the same folder as the css file referencing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not appearing because you didn't give any height to the div see this http://jsfiddle.net/ce1j6k7k/2/ you can remove the height to see the difference

HTML

```
<div id="image"></div>
```

CSS

```
#image{
width:300px;
height:300px;
background-image:url('http://placekitten.com/300/301');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resources specified in CSS are resolved relative to the path of the CSS file, not the page referencing the CSS file. `PIC1.jpg` must be located in the same directory/folder as the CSS file itself.

There is no way in CSS to do what you think it does - and that's a good thing, because I can't think of any possible use-case. Imagine having these pages all referencing `style.css`:

```
/index.html
/products/fish.html
/user/account/orderHistory
```

...if `style.css` referenced "foo.jpg" then foo.jpg would have to be replicated at `/foo.jpg`, `/products/foo.jpg` and `/user/account/foo.jpg`.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of 3 possible problems.
First, the image path. for example if this is your image's real path:
D:\Projects\MyProject\Content\Images\PIC1.jpg

you should do this in your code:

```
background-image: url('~\Content\Images\PIC1.jpg');
```

Second, is that the width that you've set in the code doesn't match the image's coordinates. In that case, you can either change the code or re-size the image.

And finally, the image might not be loaded on the page and by refreshing it few times it might be shown.